# Entity Framework - Insert if newly added to the collection, delete if removed from the collection

Tags: c#, sql, api, entity-framework, rest

I am trying to figure out the best way of doing this scenario. I have a SQL table called Contractors which is retrieved and updated using a list of checkboxes. I am using an Array of integers to keep TradeIDs.

[Below is a sample of my SQL table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci0Lq.png)

Any Contractor can have 0 or more Trades. When a user retrieve the list of Trades, update the list by adding or removing items and submitted it I want below to happen.

- Insert the TradeIDs if they doesn't exist for the Contractor in the table
- Delete the TradeIDs if they are not in the modified Array
- If they were already there in the original Array and Updated Array leave them

I found some commercial solutions like EF Extensions/ EF Plus having functions like BulkSynchronize to do this.
But what's the best way of doing this without using them?

I way I know to do this in 2 operations now is to delete all TradeIDs for a given Contractor in a loop using HttpDelete and then Add all of the modified list using HttpPost.

Below is the HttpGet function from my API.

```
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<ContractorTrade>> GetContractorTrade(int id)
    {
        var contractorTrade = _context.ContractorTrades.AsQueryable();
        contractorTrade = contractorTrade.Where(item => item.ContractorId == id).OrderBy(item => item.TradeId);
        return await contractorTrade.ToListAsync();
    }
```

I am using Angular front-end to update and send the new list to the API.

For example in the table above (ContractorID = 10)

Originally retrieved Array (sorted) will look something like below.

```
tradesCheckedList: number[] =  [3, 8, 82];
```

Updated Array (sorted) will look something like below.

```
tradesCheckedList: number[] =  [3, 12, 41, 82];
```

So, in this case I want to delete the record with TradeID = 8 (For ContractorID = 10) from the SQL table and insert new records for 12 and 41. Records for 3 and 82 should stay as they are.

Comment: Body text says 12 but sample code says 13, by the way

Comment: In an EF-Core, many-many join [See](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many). You can just reassign the skip navigation collection with the new collection. Only the changes will be saved.

Comment: @CaiusJard, Noted and updated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

LINQ Except helps here. The list of ids you have to insert is given by `newArray.Except(originalArray)`. The list of ids you have to delete is given by `originalArray.Except(newArray)` - you should thus ensure that your UI submits the original array back to you unless you want to hit the db for the current trades when the request comes in and take that as the original

Comment: Is there a way to do doth of these in a single Http call? If so what could be it? I mean something like this; Passing both original and new arrays to the API function and within the API function it checks if the original array has not modified during the round trip and doing the insertion and deletion. Are you able to provide a link to a sample code doing something like that?

Comment: That is indeed what I was envisaging; the UI will post to the back end, the original array and the new array.. or it will post jsut the new array and the back end will lookup the current settings in the db and take those as the original, then you're just doing a pair of accepts to get a "list of ID to be added" and a "list of id to be deleted", adding/deleting those things and savign the changes. I'm not sure it needs me to write it all for you; I'm sure it's no different to any other CRUD you have where you add or remove something from the DB